# Solr 6 Case insensitive query

Tags: apache, search, solr, case-insensitive

I'm looking for a way to do a case insensitive query on Solr 6. I'm using Json files. Here is my current query :

```
http://ipaddress:8983/solr/artists/select?q=title:*my string*&rows=200&wt=json&indent=true
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: whats the fieldType defined for your title? Add the lowercasefilterfactory in the fieldType..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `LowerCaseTokenizerFactory` in the fieldType used for the title field.

Add the filter at both index and query.

Check the more filters and their info at [Solr Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory)

Comment: Thanks a lot. And where do you find  the fieldType in Solr 6 ? (yes this is the first time I use Solr)

Comment: you will find the same in the schema.xml file used from any of the configfiles used to create the core artist.

Comment: I read somewhere that schema.xml doesn't exist anymore on Solr 6. Is that true ? If not where can I find it ?

Comment: which configfiles been used by you to create the core..?check there the file named managed-schema